# Running script with argument seems to cause RecursionError

Tags: python-3.x, python-unittest

I'm working on a little project with `unittest`.

I can run my tests but if I add an argument to my command line entry (e.g : `./myprogramm.py test` instead of just `./myprogramm.py`) in order to add an `argparse` layer (argparse itself doesn't seem to be the cause of the problem) a `RecursionError` occurs.

**Sample file to reproduce :**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3                                                                                                

import argparse
import unittest

def foo():
    return True

class FooTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_foo(self):
        self.assertTrue(foo())

def test():
    unittest.main()

def main():
    foo()

def make_parser():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='test or foo.')
    subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest='subcommand')
    subparsers.required = True
    subparsers.add_parser('test')
    subparsers.add_parser('foo')
    return parser

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = make_parser()
    args = parser.parse_args()
    if args.subcommand == 'test':
        test()
    elif args.subcommand == 'foo':
        main()
```

Launching this programm with `./myprogramm.py foo` works, but not if I launch it with `./myprogramm.py test`.

**Output with `RecursionError` :**

```
  File "./myprogramm.py", line 14, in test
    unittest.main()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/main.py", line 93, in __init__
    self.parseArgs(argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/main.py", line 140, in parseArgs
    self.createTests()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/main.py", line 147, in createTests
    self.module)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/loader.py", line 219, in loadTestsFromNames
    suites = [self.loadTestsFromName(name, module) for name in names]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/loader.py", line 219, in <listcomp>
    suites = [self.loadTestsFromName(name, module) for name in names]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/loader.py", line 204, in loadTestsFromName
    test = obj()
  File "./myprogramm.py", line 14, in test
    unittest.main()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/main.py", line 93, in __init__
    self.parseArgs(argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/main.py", line 114, in parseArgs
    self._initArgParsers()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/main.py", line 150, in _initArgParsers
    parent_parser = self._getParentArgParser()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/main.py", line 155, in _getParentArgParser
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/argparse.py", line 1629, in __init__
    self._positionals = add_group(_('positional arguments'))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/gettext.py", line 514, in gettext
    return dgettext(_current_domain, message)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/gettext.py", line 478, in dgettext
    codeset=_localecodesets.get(domain))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/gettext.py", line 413, in translation
    mofiles = find(domain, localedir, languages, all=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/gettext.py", line 376, in find
    val = os.environ.get(envar)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/_collections_abc.py", line 595, in get
    return self[key]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

**How could I (should I?) handle this?**

Thus far to avoid this problem, I run `del sys.argv[1]`. But is there a better way?

I guess that `unittest.main()` uses `sys.argv` and `test` as first argument triggers a particular behaviour for this function.

If I use an other keyword that `test` I get something like this (using `bar` here) :

```
E
======================================================================
ERROR: bar (unittest.loader._FailedTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError: module '__main__' has no attribute 'bar'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

FAILED (errors=1)
```